# How to append new row to Dataframe's specific column and fill missing values with Nan

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this dataframe:

```
NAME  4/6/2021  4/7/2021    #Everyday new Column is added
T1    True      False
T2    True      True
T3    False     True
T4    True      True
T5    True      True
```

Say, a new row is added with a `Name` which is not already present in the dataframe. I want to append that to the dataframe from that day onwards and with the previous dates `NaN` should be added, and if possible `False`(if not possible,I could use `fillna` to replace `NaN` with `False`).

I want the new dataframe to be something like this:

```
NAME  4/6/2021  4/7/2021  4/8/2021  #Everyday new Column is added
T1    True      False     True
T2    True      True      False
T3    False     True      True
T4    True      True      True
T5    True      True      False
T6    NaN       Nan       True     #New Row to be added
```

Comment: You can use `pd.concat` with `axis=1`

Comment: Do you mind to explain how you receive the new data? Is it a series , a dataframe or something else?

Comment: @rpanai It'd be really helpful if you could elaborate the process.

Comment: Seems to make sense to put the NaN values into the row before you add it to the Dataframe?

Comment: @rpanai I read a CSV file and after processing I receive a `pd.Series`  and I iterate through the `pd.Series` to create a list of `True` and `False`. Then I add the list to the dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first add a new empty line with :

```py
df = df.append(pd.Series(dtype=int), ignore_index=True)
```

You'll end up with :

```
NAME  4/6/2021  4/7/2021    #Everyday new Column is added
T1    True      False
T2    True      True
T3    False     True
T4    True      True
T5    True      True
T6    NaN       NaN
```

And then add your new column with :

```py
df['4/8/2021'] = [True, False, True, True, False, True]
```

Comment: How do I describe the new `NAME` in the `append` function?